# How can I run navmesh agent and raycast at the same time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm writing the code for my AI of my game in Unity, and I want to run in the same code the NavMesh agent for movement, Raycast and a sound trigger (in the context of my game, this an enemy that is sensible to sound and if it hears it, it will follow the source of it).

> **Note :**  Navigation mesh agent. This component is attached to a mobile character in the game to allow it to navigate the Scene using
>   the NavMesh
>
> Raycasting is commonly used in video game development for things such
>   as determining line of sight of the player

I've tried running 2 separate scripts together (Raycast and NavMesh) but it didn't work. I'm sorry, but I'm a total ignorant when it comes to coding in C#.

Here is the code I've wrote:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class IAVISIBILIDAD : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public float moveSpeed = 3;
    public float rotationSpeed = 3;
    public float distance = 5f;
    public bool Enabled = false;
    public bool Detect = false;
    private Transform myTransform;


    void Awake()
    {
        myTransform = this.GetComponent<Transform>();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        target = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Enabled)
        {
            myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - myTransform.position), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            RaycastHit info;
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward * distance, Color.red, 0.1f);
            if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out info, distance))
            {
                if (info.collider.tag == "Player")
                {
                    Detect = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Detect = false; 
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Detect = false;
            }
        }
        if (Enabled && Detect)
        {
            myTransform.position += myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Some recommendations, as you didn't post the full code. You should absolutely be able to do all this.**

1. **Please draw a debugging line, so you can visually see what exactly your  raycast is doing:** https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawLine.html
2. **Do some Debug.Logs in your code to figure out exactly what is happening, aka:**

**Example**

```
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out info, distance))
{
    Debug.Log("Collided with: " + info.collider.tag}");
    if (info.collider.tag == "Player")
    {
        Detect = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Detect = false; 
    }
}
else
{
    Debug.Log("Failed to collide with anything");
    Detect = false;
}
```

3. **Check  your physics layers https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html**
4. **Double  check the tags are correct**
5. **Double check there are colliders on things**

Comment: Hi Kale. Thanks for the answer. I would like to know how would you write that code, please. I really have no clue on how to do that.

Comment: This may sound strange, but I highly recommend you check this out. It's free due to COVID19, and a lot of the examples will help you be able to do multiple things like that: https://learn.unity.com/